# jQuery ready - how to strip an existing ready handle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been asked to perform maintenance on a third party site, I can edit the javascript but not the back end code. This site uses a plugin which sets various styles and events up in a jQuery.ready call. I want to stop it without causing errors. I can insert javascript before and after the plugin in the template but the markup inside the plugin comes from elsewhere. I have tried something like this:

```
<script>
    var tmpReady = $.ready;
    $.ready = function() {};
</script>
<pluginWhichICanNotChange>
    $(document).ready( function(){ BAD STUFF } );
</pluginWhichICanNotChange>
<script>
    $.ready = tmpReady;
</script>
```

But the BAD STUFF still fires. Anyone any idea how I can strip it!?

Comment: You could override `$().ready()` for while the plugin's JS is executed but that is likely to break the other plugin altogether

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the methods that work with selectors reside in the `$.fn` namespace. The following should work:

```
<script>
    var realReady = $.fn.ready;
    $.fn.ready = function() {};
</script>
<pluginWhichICanNotChange>
    $(document).ready(function() { /* BAD STUFF */ });
</pluginWhichICanNotChange>
<script>
    $.fn.ready = realReady;
</script>
```